# In unity's dash, how do I change the font colour?

Tags: fonts, unity-dash, customization, colors

I seem to have white font over a white background when I press "super" or the dash button on the launcher. Can I change the font colour or make it darker in the dash?

Comment: Have you found out how to do it?

Comment: This 5+ year old unanswered question would be based on Ubuntu 12.04 or older version which are all EOL. As such the problem cannot be reproduced. VTC as such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default system font using terminal only in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454279/change-default-system-font-using-terminal-only-in-14-04)