# Change default system font using terminal only in 14.04

Tags: unity, fonts

The following question answers how to [Adjust fonts using tweak tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size) but the luddite in me would like to know how to do this without installing `unity-tweak-tool`.

How can I adjust the default system font from a terminal.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> `gsettings` offers a simple commandline interface to GSettings. It lets you get, set or monitor an individual key for changes.

- **You can set fonts by following commands in terminal :**

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name 'Sans 10'
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Ubuntu 10'
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono 11'
  gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Ubuntu 10'
  ```
- **To Know current settings type following commands in terminal :**

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name
  gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font
  ```

***Additional:***

- To find all similar keys on schema type following command:

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.interface
  ```
- To reset all valuses of keys run following command in terminal:

  ```
  gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.interface
  ```

Comment: Application developers and end-users are recommended to use Gsettings, not Dconf directly.

Answer (score 9):

Recent updates have been changing the font scaling factors on my system, reset them with this command...

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor '1.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dconf` to change the default system font:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/font-name "'NanumGothic Italic 11'"
```

To restore the original value:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/font-name "'Ubuntu 11'"
```

**Note**: to check the current value, use the following command:

```
dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/interface/font-name
```

Comment: Deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63824/can-i-change-the-linux-console-ctrlaltf1-font-to-ubuntu-mono):

```
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/UbuntuMono-R-8x16.psf
```

this is an example; you can see a list of available fonts like this:

```
ls /usr/share/consolefonts
```

and should you for some reason not have them, you can install them like this:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console
```

note that you may need to put the setfont command in your .profile or .bashrc as it may need to be run upon every login