# How to change chrome bookmark bar font sizes

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to change the font size of chrome web browser bookmark bar on Linux?
it does't vary with zoom out and zoom in options.

Comment: Seems like this is a bug since 2009
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17866

Comment: Interesting, the [corresponding bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90034) for the bookmark bar has been closed as fixed. But in my screenshot below, it looks like both tab bar and bookmark bar are working fine.

Comment: my chrome looks really ugly due to large fonts, since i don't have 10 reputation i'm not allow to post any screenshots here anyway check this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5lW_ZYdtxZTY3NrZVZKaWJsYW8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

There was [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375824) in Chrome 35 that caused Chrome's UI fonts to be too small for many Linux users.  If you are using that version of Chrome, you should update to the latest.

If that isn't the issue, and the fonts are still too small for your preference, you can change Ubuntu's system fonts, and Chrome will respect your settings (after restarting Chrome).

Taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/454292/2079):

```
# check current font
# for me, this returns Ubuntu 11
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 

# set it to something larger
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Ubuntu 14'
```

If you prefer not to use the command line, you can change these settings using [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) [image: Install Unity Tweak Tool]

**Note** that this will change more than just Chrome's UI.  As far as I know, there is no way in Chrome's settings (or chrome://flags) to change the font size of the interface.

Before and after, with the default `11` and my change to `13`:

[image: Chrome UI Before and After]

Comment: I have changed the font size using Unity Tweak Tool, now all the other fonts are okay except chrome, chrome bookmark bar font size and the address bar font size doesn't change. 
my version is 36.0.1985.143

Comment: You've restarted Chrome since changing system fonts?  My changes didn't take effect until I restarted.

Comment: already i have restarted, even restarted the pc, nothing changed