# Font change after turning on PC

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I turned off my PC (Ubuntu 14.04) and when I turned it back on the fonts had changed (file names, folder names etc.). Why did this happen and how can I change the fonts again?

Now is this way:

[image]

Comment: Can we see a screenshot? Press print screen and it will be added into your Pictures folder, then you can add to the post.

Comment: @Tim Yes sure. I edited my post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change default system font using terminal only in 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454279/change-default-system-font-using-terminal-only-in-14-04)

Comment: @Tim I have seen this post. My main concern is why the fonts were changed. Also it didn't help me as through the terminal I can't see how each font looks.

Comment: Why this happened is not really a question we can answer without forensics on your computer.  If you would like a GUI version, have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's the font/UI scaling. There is a bug declared in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1317253

To change the default font there is a similar question [Change default system font using terminal only in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454279/change-default-system-font-using-terminal-only-in-14-04)

Answer (score 2):

Using "Unity Tweak Tool" you can customize your default font and themes,

Command to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool
```

You may be asked your system password, for installation.

To open Unity Tweak Tool, open the Dash and search for Unity, open the `Unity - > Appearance` section and select your customized themes and fonts. Check they work after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late, but I think this answer can help someone

Just execute this code and restart your computer

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade